# Can a MacOS launch daemon present UI?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-sierra, launchd

According to Apple's documentation, a launch daemon runs in a system context and cannot present UI:
[image: Apple background process table]
[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/DesigningDaemons.html)

However, as a test I created a simple launchd plist below to point to my MacOS application on Sierra, and after executing `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/myapp.plist`, the process started up as the root user and the Main Window appeared.

What gives?  Shouldn't the UI be disallowed somehow?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>myapp</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>myapp</string>
<string>--background</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is where I check how it is running:

```
$ ps aux | grep myapp
dyoung           55912   0.0  0.0  2432804    800 s009  S+    9:14AM   
0:00.00 grep myapp
root             55176   0.0  0.1  2628312  23416   ??  Ss    8:43AM   0:01.04 /Users/dyoung/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gsnwymohiqyegccsqziyfxdiztci/Build/Products/
```